# Why am I getting ValueError in Python and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, valueerror

```
a=[]
b=[]
t=int(input())
for j in range(0,t):
    n=int(input())
    k=int(input())
    for i in range(0, n):
        element=int(input())
        a.append(element)
    for i in range(n-k, n):
        b.append(a[i])
    for i in range(0, n-k):
        b.append(a[i])
    print(b)
```

[image]

Comment: `input()` reads a full line from the user. The screenshot indicates that you're getting multiple integers on one line. You need to do some additional parsing to read the input correctly.

Comment: Think about how you could get the input `5 2` (separated with space), and converting each to `int`.

Comment: Please replace the images with formatted code/text in the question. See also: [ask] and [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Comment: What are you expecting `k` to be when the input is `5 2`?

Answer (score 0):

You write 5 2 instead of 52
The first is sepereated with space and it will be no lo longer an integer .however the second is the correct so write 52